# Two dimensional vector of integer C++. What's wrong?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have trouble with two dimensional vector. Example:

```
vector < vector<int> > data;

int i = 0;
int int_value;
while (i < 10 )
{   
    cin >> int_value;
    data[i].push_back (int_value);
}
```

I want using push_back for back insert and then I want use data [i][j]. Where is the problem?

Comment: Can you tell us what error you're encountering?

Comment: The loop never ends, does it?

Comment: probably needs `data[i++].push_back(int_value);`, but the code looks very weird to me with that doubled vector.

Answer (score 4):

You need to initialize vector `data` before using `data[i]`. Otherwise, the vector is empty and accessing `data[i]` is out of range. Also, you need to increment `i` inside the `while` loop:

```
vector < vector<int> > data(10); // creates a vector of size 10,
                                 // each element being an empty vector of int's
int int_value;
for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)
{   
  cin >> int_value;
  data[i].push_back (int_value); // add int_value to the ith vector
}
```

After the loop, each vector contains one `int` value entered by the user.

Answer (score 1):

`data[i]` does not exist, because the empty constructor of vector creates a vector of size 0. So when you call `data[i]` this will be out of bounds. Just like a one dimensional vector first allocate enough elements for data. In your case it seems you need to have data of size 10:

```
vector < vector<int> > data(10);
```

Also you never increase `i` in the while loop which it seems will lead to infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have an empty vector of vectors, and you are trying to access its elements (`data[i]`). Obviously, you can't do that before you add some (via `push_back`, `resize` or some other method of `data` itself).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `data[i]` does not exist. First you need to push a `vector<int>` into the `vector< vector<int> >` vector, then you can add integers to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
vector < vector<int> > data;
```

`data` is an empty vector which holds `vector<int>`.

```
data[i].push_back (int_value);
```

`data` is empty. So, doing `data[i]` leads to undefined behavior.